# Replace with sed using variable and adding too

Tags: linux, variables, unix, sed, replace

i'm making this replace

`sed 's/<n3:CustId>.*<\/n3:CustId>/<n3:CustId>'"${orgkey}"'<\/n3:CustId>/' CAMBIOMINI.txt > CAMBIOMINI2.txt`

but now i want to replace line by line with a differente orgkey value, i want orgkey+=1 but i dont know how to make that in the same command for all the CAMBIOMINI.txt file

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: edit your Q to include small sample input and your required output from that input. Also include your changing (?) values for `$orgkey`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sed` may not be suitable for the case that you want to alter the substitution
for each occurance.
If my undersanding of your requirement is correct, following would work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {orgkey[++i]=$0; next}
 {print gensub(/<n3:CustId>[^<]*<\/n3:CustId>/,"<n3:CustId>" orgkey[++j] "</n3:CustId>", "g")} ' orgkey.txt CAMBIOMINI1.txt
```

where `orgkey.txt` holds the list of substitutions:

```
orgkey_a
orgkey_b
orgkey_c
orgkey_d
```

and `CAMBIOMINI1.txt` will look like:

```
<n3:CustId>id1</n3:CustId>
<n3:CustId>id2</n3:CustId>
<n3:CustId>id3</n3:CustId>
<n3:CustId>id4</n3:CustId>
```

then the result will be:

```
<n3:CustId>orgkey_a</n3:CustId>
<n3:CustId>orgkey_b</n3:CustId>
<n3:CustId>orgkey_c</n3:CustId>
<n3:CustId>orgkey_d</n3:CustId>
```

Note that it does not assume the tag in `CAMBIOMINI1.txt` appears multiple
times in the same line as:

```
<n3:CustId>id1</n3:CustId> <n3:CustId>id2</n3:CustId>
<n3:CustId>id3</n3:CustId>
<n3:CustId>id4</n3:CustId>
```

In that case, use a Perl version instead:

```
perl -nle 'if (@ARGV) {push(@orgkey, $_); next}
    s#<n3:CustId>.*?</n3:CustId>#"<n3:CustId>" . $orgkey[$j++] . "</n3:CustId>"#ge; print' orgkey.txt CAMBIOMINI1.txt
```